# Why does mysql insist on using IPs instead of hostnames?

Tags: mysql

FOr example ...

```
grant select on mydb.* to 'myuser'@'dashboard.domain.com' identified by 'mypasswd';
flush privileges;
```

From my client, I try to connect ...

```
mysql -umyuser -p -h MYSQLSERVER
```

I put in the password and I get ...

```
ERROR 1130 (00000): Host '10.199.1.110' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

And yes, reverse DNS is working for both my client and server.

Answer (score 1):

May be, because you need to grand privileges to connect *from* your host, not to connect *to* MySQL`s host?

```
grant select on mydb.* to 'myuser'@'myclient_ip' identified by 'mypasswd';
flush privileges;
```

Comment: stupid me, yea it's 'myclient_hostname' i typed it in wrong above. Let me edit the post.

Comment: So, are you sure that your MySQL server is open for remote connections? Try to configure it according to this: http://hashmysql.org/wiki/Remote_Clients_Cannot_Connect or any other manual There you can find, also, how to setup a user to connect from remote host

Comment: if i grant it per IP it works, it doesn't work via "hostnames."